# Grouping a data set into two groups with minimum difference in selected variables

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, statistics

I have a data set with few variables I want to split the data set into two groups and I want the difference in these two groups to be as minimum as possible.  Suppose I have a variable as `price`, I want the final two groups to have minimum difference in their total price. Number of records in each group is not that critical. I want the final two groups to have the minimum difference in the total values of selected variables. 
Solution preferred in python.

Sample Data :

ID     Value          V1     V2  V3      V4      V5

1    $31,350.00     14.33%  732 120 23.6%   26%

2    $9,240.00      14.33%      120 30.4%   34%

3    $12,257.00     6.45%   797 36  1.4%    4%

So I want to divide this dataset into two groups such that the groups have minimum difference in the total value, mean v1,v2,v3,v4,v5

Comment: You will need to post a sample data with what you have tried, and what you desire as output. See [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: ID   Value   V1   V2   V3   V4   V5 
1  $31,350.00  14.33% 732 120 23.6% 26%
2  $9,240.00  14.33%  120 30.4% 34%
3  $12,257.00  6.45% 797 36 1.4% 4%
4  $20,700.00  7.08% 785 120 3.1% 3%
5  $9,240.00  11.83% 704 120 13.0% 24%
6  $11,550.00  13.70% 692 36 14.4% 38%

Answer (score 0):

I would work the problem by first sorting the column with prices (`'Value'`) and calculating the maximum difference in the sorted data. Then split the data there.

Example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID': [1,2,3,4,5,6],
                   'Value': [31350, 9240, 500, 1000, 200, 28000]})

# indices corresponding to sorted data
ix_sorted = df['Value'].argsort()

# get the differences with .diff() and the index corresponding to max difference with .idxmax()
ix_max = df['Value'][ix_sorted].diff().idxmax() - 1 

#split, using .iloc
df1, df2 = df.iloc[ix_sorted[:ix_max]], df.iloc[ix_sorted[ix_max:]] 

df1

>>   ID  Value
4   5    200
2   3    500
3   4   1000
1   2   9240

df2
>>  ID  Value
5   6  28000
0   1  31350
```